# Drupal 7 EntityFieldQuery

Tags: join, drupal-7, entity, transformation

I'm new to Drupal 7 coming from Drupal 6.  In 6 I used to build custom modules and use standard db_query's to query CCK fields.  In doing so I was able to use things like JOINs and `LOWER(REPLACE(n.title, ' ', '_')) = '%s'`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do either using EntityFieldQuery.  The concept behind EFQ seems pretty straight forward, but in terms of field conditions, it looks like I can only check the value of a specific field using an operator.  What if I want to use the code above to check if the transformed value is equal to my value?

Since it loads what it needs to perform the query and fetch the NIDs and VIDs, it seems as though I won't need to use JOINs because it's considering everything it needs for the specified content type.  Is using:

```
$query->entityCondition('bundle', array('article', 'page'));
```

and

```
$query->propertyCondition('type', array('article', 'page', 'blog'));
```

effectively the same a JOIN statement?  Do both statements use the NIDs to join the various content types?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 0):

One of the main benefits of EntityFieldQuery is that it doesn't care what field backend you are using. To accomplish that, it doesn't provide complex operations, since it has to support the subset of options that would also work for a backend like MongoDB.

If you have to do such complex queries in SQL on field values, maybe it would be better to re-think your field schema.